# Create li tag without and word in tag(empty)?

Tags: css, spacing, html

I have this code :

```
<li class="eight"  ><a href="#" >music</a></li>
```

but i want that have the same code without any word inside (empty) my mean is remove music word but still have the same width of li tag,is it possible?,or better say that how can i put space character in li tag?
thanks

Comment: you can append spaces &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

Comment: Pandiya Chendur,Thanks, your solution is ok also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.eight a {
    display: block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:100px;
}
```

you can change the offset of your text with text-indent